# Is there cheap way of retrieving EUID from PI

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, filesystems, fanotify

I've recently tried to write a program that monitors activity on filesystem. I'd like it to record action, PID, executable name and **EUID**. I've used `fanotify` for this purpose and it can retrieve everything except EUID. So far I've been able to fetch user using following code:

```
#include <proc/readproc.h>

struct passwd* get_user_from_pid(pid_t pid)
    {
        proc = openproc(PROC_FILLMEM | PROC_FILLSTAT | PROC_FILLSTATUS| PROC_FILLUSR | PROC_PID, &pid);
        memset(&proc_info, 0, sizeof(proc_info));
        if (readproc(proc, &proc_info) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        struct passwd* user_info = getpwnam(proc_info.euser);
        closeproc(proc);
        return user_info;
    }
```

The problem is that as far as I know underneath it just reads files from /proc/<pid> which is ofcourse slow when dealing with huge amount of I/O traffic, almost always keeping CPU at 100% utilization.

Is there a cheaper way to achieve the same?

Comment: This question has an [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408613/how-to-get-the-ruid-euid-suid-and-rgid-egid-sgid-of-a-process).

Comment: I suspect the inefficiency isn't so much in openproc as in getpwnam. Haven't checked, but you might try memoizing your results, no one sane reuses a uid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just read `/proc/<pid>/status` with scanf ?

Comment: program might prefer to parse /proc/PID/stat

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.   It belongs in comments under the original post.